# Disable/Enable form submit button with ember validations status

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-validations

I am adding form validations using "ember-validations" plugin. I am able to do inline validations, but I need to disable/enable button based on the validation status.

**Component.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend(EmberValidations, {
validations: {
    'model.firstName': {
      presence: true,
      presence: { message: 'Please enter valid first name.' }      
    },
    'model.lastName': {
      presence: true,
      presence: { message: 'Please enter valid last name.' }      
    },
    'model.email': {
      presence: true ,
      presence: { message: 'Please enter valid email name.' }     
    },
    'model.department': {
      presence: true,
      presence: { message: 'Please enter valid department name.' }      
    },
}
});
```

**Template.hbs**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="fname">First Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    {{validated-input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value=model.firstName errors=errors.model.firstName}}
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  {{validated-input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value=model.lastName errors=errors.model.lastName}}
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
   {{validated-input type="email" placeholder="Email" value=model.email errors=errors.model.email}}
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="department">Department:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    {{validated-input type="text" placeholder="Department" value=model.department errors=errors.model.department}}
</div>
</div>
{{#bs-button classNames="table-btn" action=(action "saveAction" model) buttonType="button" type="update"}}Save{{/bs-button}}
</form>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

How can I get the total form inputs validation status while using **ember validations**, so that i can use that flag for disable/enable button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [ember-validations docs](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-validations):

```
user.validate().then(function() {
  // all validations pass
  user.get('isValid'); // true
}).catch(function() {
  // any validations fail
  user.get('isValid'); // false
}).finally(function() {
  // all validations complete
  // regardless of isValid state
 user.get('isValid'); // true || false
});
```

I would guess you could set a computed property aliasing `yourModel.get("isValid")`:

```
// in your controller or component:
isSaveButtonDisabled: Ember.computed.not("user.isValid")
```

And then in your template:

```
...
</div>
{{#bs-button classNames="table-btn" disabled=isSaveButtonDisabled action=(action "saveAction" model) buttonType="button" type="update"}}Save{{/bs-button}}
</form>
```

I am just not sure what is the syntax for your `bs-button` for `disabled=isSaveButtonDisabled`.

Comment: Thanks Pavol for the response. We need to move the validation from component.js to model. Otherwise it will give error validate is not a function. I modified code like that, and it worked.